# Вывод общих друзей

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста. Есть таблица frnds и 3 поля. id,user_one,user_two
там три записи user_one=1 дружит с user_two=2 итд. Как вывести общих друзей ? есть скрипт вывода вообщем всех друзей выглядит он так.

```
$frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one='$id' OR user_two='$id'ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 6");

while ($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)){

$user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
$user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
if ($user_one == $myrow['id']) {
  $id = $user_two;
} else{

$id = $user_one;
}
$avatar = getuser($id,'avatar');
$username = getuser($id,'username');
$family = getuser($id,'family');

echo "<div class='fr'>";
echo "<a href='/id$id'>";

echo "<img src='/".$avatar."' width=60px height='60px'border=0px>";
echo "<div class='fr-us-fm'>$username <br />$family</div></a>";
echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Где задается $myrow['id'] ?

Comment: На всякий случай. Не используйте `ORDER by RAND()` - тормознутая штука

Comment: На всякий случай. Не используйте ORDER by RAND() - тормознутая штука
Спасибо учту, а как можно реализовать что бы при обновлении страницы выводились по разному? замена Rand есть?

Comment: вот ссылка про оптимизацию ORDER BY RAND()
http://hudson.su/2010/09/16/mysql-optimizaciya-order-by-rand/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [общие друзья запрос mysql](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444172/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d1%8c%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

ищем общих друзей для 2-х юзеров

```
<?
$user_one = 1;
$user_two = 2;
$sql = "SELECT t1.user_two FROM `frnds` AS t1 INNER JOIN `frnds` AS t2 ON t2.user_one = {$user_two} WHERE t1.user_two = t2.user_two AND t1.user_one = {$user_one} GROUP BY t1.user_two";
$r = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($l = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) 
{
echo $l['user_two']."<br>\r\n";
}
?>
```

вот как-то так)

Comment: Извините объясните мне пожалуйста что означает t1 и t2 ? Иногда просто встречал такое.

Comment: это псевдонимы таблиц, JOIN'ами мы можем соединять несколько разных таблиц, в данном случае мы подключаем одну и ту же таблицу и задаем псевдонимы, чтобы отличать основную таблицу от подключаемой

Comment: t1  и t2 могут быть любыми, я отталкивался от table1 table2 просто сокращая до t1 t2

Comment: @levantez А понял простите но что то ваш код не работает.Какие еще могут быть варианты?

Comment: а в чем ошибка? все должно работать, подразумевается что user_one и user_two целые числа, иначе эти переменные надо взять в одинарные кавычки в SQL запросе, скиньте дамп таблицы с несколькими строками, посмотрю что не так

Comment: @levantez


--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `frnds`
--

INSERT INTO `frnds` (`id`, `user_one`, `user_two`) VALUES
(11, 2, 6),
(2, 1, 5),
(10, 6, 1),
(4, 1, 7),
(5, 1, 8),
(6, 1, 9),
(9, 2, 1),
(8, 9, 10),
(12, 10, 6);

такой вот.

Comment: подразумевается что user_one это ID пользователя, а user_two это id друга, тогда в вашем дампе у пользователя 1 нет общих друзей с пользователем 2, добавте строку в таблицу ну например (13,2,5) - тогда получится что пользователь 1 с пользователем 2 имеют общего друга 5, запрос SELECT t1.user_two FROM `frnds` AS t1 INNER JOIN `frnds` AS t2 ON t2.user_one = 2 WHERE t1.user_two = t2.user_two AND t1.user_one = 1 GROUP BY t1.user_two - подтвердит вам это, другими словами мы ищем общий user_two для двух разных user_one

Comment: @levantez,а все понял спасибо вам огромное.Извините еще вопрос, сможете мне помочь с сообщениями пожалуйста?