# общие друзья запрос mysql

Tags: mysql

Помогите разобраться, как одним запросом вывести общих друзей?

БД с друзьями:

```
CREATE TABLE `m_friends` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `friend_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `friend_id_user_id` (`friend_id`, `user_id`)
);
```

БД с пользователями:

```
  CREATE TABLE `m_userdata` (
        `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `user_type` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `user_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
    );
```

Comment: я обновил ответ вторым запросом, где выводятся общие (при их наличии) друзья для всех пар пользователей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например, так.

- первый запрос — общие друзья для пользователей с идентификаторами `1` и `2`;
- второй запрос — общие друзья для всех пар пользователей (у которых есть общие друзья).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f09ad/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table u (id int, n text);

insert into u values
   (1, "вася")
  ,(2, "оля")
  ,(3, "юра")
  ,(4, "маша")
  ,(5, "борис")
  ,(6, "аня")
;

create table f (user int, friend int);

insert into f values
   (1, 3)
  ,(1, 4)
  ,(1, 5)
  ,(2, 3)
  ,(2, 4)
  ,(2, 6)
  ,(3, 4)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select f1.friend, u.n
from f f1
join f f2
  on f2.user = 2
  and f2.friend = f1.friend
join u
  on u.id = f1.friend
where f1.user = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f09ad/4/0)**:

```
| friend |    n |
|--------|------|
|      3 |  юра |
|      4 | маша |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select f1.user, f2.user, f1.friend, u.n
from f f1
join f f2
  on f2.friend = f1.friend
  and f2.user > f1.user
join u
  on u.id = f1.friend
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f09ad/4/1)**:

```
| user | user | friend |    n |
|------|------|--------|------|
|    1 |    2 |      3 |  юра |
|    1 |    2 |      4 | маша |
|    1 |    3 |      4 | маша |
|    2 |    3 |      4 | маша |
```

Comment: `select u.user_id,u.user_name
from m_friends f1
join m_friends f2
  on f2.user_id = 1
  and f2.friend_id = f1.friend_id
join m_userdata u
  on u.user_id = f1.user_id
where f1.user_id = 3` 

спасибо за помощь, что-то не уловил правда логики, выдается по моему примеру одинаковые u.id. u.user_name . Можете подсказать в чем проблема?